# Rails - "Cannot write unknown attribute" for single-sided reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a simple rails app with two models, `Product` and `Subject`.  `Product` references a single `Subject` and has the field `subject_id` in its db table.

Subsequently, `Product.rb` contains:

```
has_one :subject
```

`Subject`, however, does not reference `Product`, as it's not necessary.

When I'm trying to create a new `Product`, however, I'm having trouble assigning a `Subject` to the `Product`.  I get an error:

```
can't write unknown attribute `product_id`
```

on the marked row of `ProductsController#create` below (where `product_params` is a list of form parameters and `params[:product][:subject_id]` is a user-supplied subject id):

```
@product = Product.new(product_params)
@subject = Subject.find(params[:product][:subject_id])
--> @product.subject = @subject
```

I believe that it is complaining because the table `subjects` doesn't contain a field `product_id`, but it should need one since `Subject` doesn't reference `Product`.

Is it possible to create a single-sided reference like this, or is it necessary to always have a one-to-one or one-to-many reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model that has the "other_model_id" column has to declare a "belongs_to" relationship, not a "has_one" relationship. Change your code to `belongs_to :subject`

Check the rails guides https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

EDIT: FYIO, you don't need those `@subject = Subject.find(params[:product][:subject_id]` and `@product.subject = @subject` lines, the new already handles that if you permit the :subject_id param on product_params

Comment: Thank you! `belongs_to` suggested a different type of relationship to me, but this worked perfectly.